# Split data with regex into class of properties with C# and Regex

Tags: c#, regex

So I have data like this:

```
((4886.03 12494.89 "LYR3_SIG2"))
```

It is always going to be SPACE delimited thus I want to use Regex to place each into a property.

Yes, I was playing around with some regex

```
string q = "4886.03 12494.89 \"LYR3_SIG2";
string clean = Regex.Replace(q, @"[^\w\s]", string.Empty);
```

but what I aim to do is to put each of the 3 values into a class like this

```
public class BowTies
{
    public double XCoordinate { get; set; }
    public double YCoordinate { get; set; }
    public string Layer { get; set; }
}
```

Now I originally was parsing the data into a property

```
t = streamReader.ReadLine();
if ((t != null) && Regex.IsMatch(t, "(\\(\\()[a-zA-Z_,\\s\".0-9-]{1,}(\"\\)\\))"))
   currentVioType.Bowtie = new ParseType() { Formatted = Regex.Match(t, "(\\(\\()[a-zA-Z_,\\s\".0-9-]{1,}(\"\\)\\))").Value.Trim('(', ')'), Original = t };
```

But now I really want to put that data into the doubles and string
thus this data is space delimited  ((4886.03 12494.89 "LYR3_SIG2"))
I was started down my path of refactoring , but I temporarily was not using the regex for getting the doubles  ( which are ALWAYS going to be the first 2 values, followed by a string  so I started doing this:

```
currentAddPla.Bows.Add(new BowTies() { XCoordinate = 44.33, YCoordinate = 344.33, Layer = Regex.Match(t, "(\\(\\()[a-zA-Z_,\\s\".0-9-]{1,}(\"\\)\\))").Value.Trim('(', ')')});
```

but I obviously need to use regex and parse this dumping the first value (the double into XCoordinate,  then the 2nd value into YCoordinate and the 3rd value that regex is already getting ALL the data and needs to only get the 3rd value of "LYR3_SIG2" which should be found with regex right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It is always going to be SPACE delimited thus

RegEx for this sounds like overkill. Have you considered using `string.Split(' ');`, eg:

```
string s = "((4886.03 12494.89 \"LYR3_SIG2\"))";
s = s.Replace("(", string.Empty).Replace(")", string.Empty);
string[] arr = s.Split(' ');

currentAddPla.Bows.Add(new BowTies() { 
   XCoordinate = Convert.ToDouble(arr[0]),
   YCoordinate = Convert.ToDouble(arr[1]),
   Layer = arr[3]});
```

Comment: +1, same thing I was about to say except with code instead of argument against regex ;)

Comment: sweet!  just had to fix Layer = arr[2]});  (the accidental 3 )  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should just use `String.Split` instead of RegEx. The data is formatted simply enough that RegEx would be overkill even if it worked well here. On top of that the language which defines your data is not regular ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language ) and thus cannot be reliably parsed with RegEx. It may be working right now because the data inside the parens is simply formatted but languages which have matching braces are context-free and in general are not able to be parsed with regular expressions.